emacs keybinding caps to control in Ubuntu Server VM with i3/LightDM
Getting quite frustrated and have referenced everything I can (emacs wiki, related overflow q's), I feel like I've tried near everything to rebind my caps lock to control in order to use it as my ctrl mod in emacs.
I've used gnome-tweaks, I've tried an .xmodmap file (including applying it on restart and running xmodmap ~/.xmodmap, and I've tried editing /etc/default/keyboard with the ctrl:nocaps option. Nothing seems to work for me through any number of restarts. My xmodmap:
clear lock 
clear control 
keycode 66 = control_L 
keycode 37 = control_L 
add control = Control_L Control_R

xev and keyboardtester.com successfully read my caps key as an additional control_L, but no matter which emacs I open (via rofi drun, via sudo, -nw, calling it from alacritty) it doesn't recognize the caps lock key as being pressed. Has anyone dealt with this before? I'm not sure if it's because I'm using a macbook/VMware Fusion, or if I simply tried too many routes and now they're conflicting somehow. Any help appreciated!
